# Entity insertions at Orion increasingly slower

Tags: fiware-orion

When I have a lot of information in Context Orion Broker (in MongoDB) and when I try to insert more information increasingly your insertion is slower.
E.g.: at this moment basically I have in Orion 3GB of information and when I try to send more information to Orion, I'm waiting more or less 15 minutes to send 50MB, however, if I send the same information when the Orion was empty this process finish in 1 minute.

```
admin   0.000GB    
config  0.000GB    
local   0.000GB
orion   2.932GB
```

Is normally this process? I mean, increasingly your insertion to be slower.

Extra info: VPS Linux with 2 cores and 8GB ram.

Indexes information:

```
> use orion
switched to db orion
> show collections
entities
> db.entities.getIndexes()
[
        {
                "v" : 2,
                "key" : {
                        "_id" : 1
                },
                "name" : "_id_",
                "ns" : "orion.entities"
        },
        {
                "v" : 2,
                "key" : {
                        "location.coords" : "2dsphere"
                },
                "name" : "location.coords_2dsphere",
                "ns" : "orion.entities",
                "2dsphereIndexVersion" : 3
        },
        {
                "v" : 2,
                "key" : {
                        "expDate" : 1
                },
                "name" : "expDate_1",
                "ns" : "orion.entities",
                "expireAfterSeconds" : 0
        }
]
```

Comment: I'd need to know your index setup at DB. I mean, the result of the `db.entities.getIndexes()` command in the mongo console in the database corresponding to Orion (I mean, run that command after running mongo shell with `mongo`, then `use orion` or `use orion-<service>` if your entities are in a particular service). Could you edit your question post to include that information, please? Thx!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply... my question was updated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now is fast... i use this(as you said): db.entities.createIndex({"_id.id": 1, "_id.type": 
1, "_id.servicePath": 1}) 
Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

To speed up Orion DB operations you should create the indexes to optimize performance recommended in [performance tunning Orion documentation](https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/master/admin/perf_tuning/index.html#database-indexes). In particular:

- `{_id.servicePath: 1, _id.id: 1, _id.type: 1}` (note that this is a compound index and key order matters in this case)
- `creDate`

Comment: Thanks for your reply... I was created entities like this: { "id": "Room1", "type": "Room", "temperature": { "value": 23, "type": "Float" }, "pressure": { "value": 720, "type": "Integer" } }

With unique id. My question /doubt is, pratical terms how i can create INDEX to this sample? With this post request: localhost:1026/v2/entities

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Not sure of understanding your doubt... Do you mean how to create indexes in MongoDB?

Comment: oh, ok ! I understood now, i Need create índex in MongoDB... I thought that we need send a new parameter with a new entity. I Will create a  índex in Mongo to ID..

Comment: To be precise, it is not a matter of create "an index" (any index) in MongoDB, but the 2 ones I suggest in my answer ;)

Comment: Now is fast... i use this(as you said): db.entities.createIndex({"_id.id": 1, "_id.type": -1, "_id.servicePath": 1})       . Thank you @fgalan

Comment: I suggested `"_id.type": 1` in my answer, but I guess that for that particular use case (insertions) it doesn't matter the sub-key direction. Thus, happy to know you finally solved it! :) Could you provide a +1 to the answer and mark it as valid, please? It is not to feed my ego ;) but to give it relevance so it can be useful to other people in similar situation.